# rm: Unable to remove directory <some/sub/directory>: Device busy

Tags: directory, solaris, rm

Solaris 11.3

My script needs to recursive delete in a directory.

Other directories work fine.

One directory is plagued by the following:

```
rm -rf: Unable to remove directory <some/sub/directory>: Device busy
```

I found a post that said "shared folder" was the issue, but doesn't seem to be the fix.

I have tried:

```
#share - got nothing    
lsof: command not found
```

privs seem ok

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root           4 Jan  3 13:25 dir2/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root     root           9 Jan  8 20:16 bad_dir1/

fuser -cu  /bad_dir1
/bad_dir1:
```

Rewrote my script to ensure it returns to original calling directory.

Anything else I can look for?

Comment: Is the directory (or one of its parents) an active mount point?

Comment: *`lsof: command not found`*  The [POSIX standard way to determine if a file/directory is open is `fuser`.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fuser.html)  Solaris uses that.

Comment: Assuming "/bad_dir1" is the root directory of your "rm -rf" command, what does  the command "mount | grep /bad_dir1" give you?

Comment: Under Solaris 11, you can also use `netstat -u` to get useful information on open files/ports.

Comment: @L.Ray  ````mount | grep bad_dir1
/bad_dir1 on bad_dir1 read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/nonbmand/exec/xattr/atime/dev=4750007 on Wed Nov 22 14:11:29 2017
/bad_dir1/Sol_Audit on bad_dir1/Sol_Audit read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/nonbmand/exec/xattr/atime/dev=4750008 on Wed Nov 22 14:11:29 2017````

Comment: @sleepyweasel  netstat -u |grep bad_dir shows nothing

Comment: @HaukeLaging  cat /etc/vfstab does not have /bad_dir in it

Comment: My dir2 looks like this:  /zones2/myhost/root/Oracle_Audit on dir2/Oracle_Audit read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/nonbmand/exec/xattr/atime/zone=myhost/nozonemod/sharezone=28/dev=47501f5 on Thu Dec 14 18:59:36 2017

Comment: A directory can be a moint point without being in `fstab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your 'mount | grep bad_dir1' command looks a little strange to me, but you have a filesystem mounted on bad_dir1/Sol_Audit.  You won't be able to remove the directory while it's mounted.  Try unmounting it first:

```
$ sudo umount /bad_dir1/Sol_Audit
```

and then try running your "rm" command again.